# Timed tasks in PHP

Tags: php, timer, phpmyadmin, cron

I have an application which stores information on different tasks, each task has a duration when it must be completed (1-3 months) and if not an email alert is sent to a predefined recipient.

I have read up on this and seen that it is mainly done with cron jobs but I cannot find any example or tutorial which can show me how to write a cron job in php (most I come acroos are on cPanel) I am running xampp on windows 7.

My idea of how I would like to go about this is;

1) Have a cron job (cron_trigger.php) trigger a script (date_checker.php) once everyday

2) In my date_checker.php I scan through the database looking for uncompleted tasks and send alerts

I am quite new to PHP so I would like to know I can go about setting this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looking to run PHP from task scheduler.

I have not experimented with task scheduler as much, but from the command line you will need to point to

`C:\xampp\php\php.exe LinktoPHPFile`

Comment: So is this the option for Windows? Seeing as Cron only for Linux?

Comment: task scheduler = windows, cronjobs = linux   make the batch file you create in a known and perminant position on your computer. Ie. `C:\Tasks`

Answer (score -1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Cronjobs is linux only, but I'm sure there is something like this for windows.

A cronjob has a config file which you can open e.g. with crontab -e (opens config for your user)

Then you have something like this:

```
*    *    *    *    *  command to be executed
*/5    *    *    *    *  php /absolute/path/to/your/cron_trigger.php
```

This script runs every five minutes.

Comment: User is running windows 7 & xampp -- also, crontab only runs when the user is logged in. `/etc/crontab` is what should be edited

Comment: I read this. and mentiond it. I have a cronjob configured in crontab -e and it runs. I'm not logged in. depending on distro? I have a ubuntu.